# SOAP UI automate request Endpoint

Tags: soap, automation, soapui, soap-client

im working with Soap Ui and we have some Workspaces with a lot of projects that have 3 requests for dev, pro etc.

We wanna change the dev and other one properties cause we changed the endpoint URL, doing it mannually is gonna be the most teadious and time consuming task ever done, so im trying to automate with a script or a bash script that changes the xml properties of the requests

I dont know if this is even possible cause i have little knowledge about Soap Ui so if i could get some help about if this is possible or how to do it you would make my day

Sorry for my english and my basic/bad explanation and thank u to those who respond

Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

The SoapUI project is a plain-text XML file. You can write a script that does a search and replace in that file if you want to run in a different environment. In Groovy, it would be this:

```
def projectFileA = new File('/path/to/your/soapui-project.xml')
def projectFileB = projectFileA.text.replaceAll('xmlns:api="http://someuri/"', 'xmlns:api="http://someotheruri/"')
projectfileA.text = projectfileB
```